# How can I decrypt a VPN pre-shared key?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, encryption

I have a windows 7 *.cmp file which contains an encrypted pre-shred key in it and I also know the pin-code for it.

```
[Profile Format]
Version=5

[Connection Manager]
CMSFile=xxx\yyy.cms
PresharedKey=*************==
PresharedKeyIsEncrypted=1
```

The question is what do I do to decrypt the key and view it in plaintext?

Answer (score 0):

If your up for a little programming, it looks like it has been [answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503974/decrypting-pkcs7-encrypted-data-in-c-sharp)

and that contains a link to some [sample code](https://web.archive.org/web/20100327135133/http://www.example-code.com/csharp/crypt_decrypt_p7m.asp)

otherwise there are probably a few programs that can do it, but that might be more of a question for [software recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) than here